# Invoke a control to set a property

Tags: c#, asp.net, invoke

I have this exact issue

[ASP.net can’t update page from event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626313/asp-net-cant-update-pagefrom-event-handler)

and it's been answered! My only problem is I don't really understand the solution. How does one *Invoke the control when setting the property.*

I have a label control but there doesn't seem to be an Invoke property/method on it.

I tried this...

```
PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Label1);
        PropertyDescriptor myProperty = properties.Find("Text", false);
        myProperty.SetValue(Label1, "my value");
```

but that seemed to be the same as

```
label1.text = "my value"
```

which didn't work

Comment: Are you sure you are not overwriting the things on PostBack?

Comment: What do you mean by "invoke the control"?

Comment: @marc exaclty! I've no idea :-$ I was hoping someone could explain it more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd Invoke a control like this:

```
this.label1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        this.label1.Test = "my value";
    }));
```

Unfortunately there seems to be no Invoke method on a WebControls.Label.

One way around this is to [write web method which returns a string in web service and set it to Label.Text](http://forums.asp.net/p/1031914/1422467.aspx#1422467), I found an example [**here**](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020117.htm).

Comment: the label control doesn't seem to have an InvokeRequired method. I get the error: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label' does not contain a definition for 'InvokeRequired'

Comment: @Rob, sorry didn't realise that the WebControls.Label doesn't support that. Added some links that might help you with a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

delegate void UIDelegate(object component, object value);

```
if (this.save_button.InvokeRequired)
{
    this.save_button.Invoke(new UIDelegate(TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this.save_button).Find("Enabled", false).SetValue),
                                new object[] { this.save_button, true });
}
else
{
    this.save_button.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: See the previous answer: InvokeRequired doesn't work for web controls.